# Collect to list and then pass it in lambda or consumer java 8

Tags: java, java-stream, consumer

Is it possible to collect to list using `.collect(Collectors.toList())` and then pass this whole list (not like `.forEach` stuff) forward to some consumer or function if the list is not empty? I don't want to declare a list variable to pass it to my next method and use if braces for this.

Comment: Yes, it's possible: `.collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(element -> consumer.action(element))`

Comment: `someMethod(stream.collect(toList()))`? But this generally makes the code harder to read, understand and debug. What's wrong with local variables?

Comment: I want to pass my whole list to the method if it's not empty, that is the problem. I dont want to trigger method with empty list and want to do this without any ifs blocks.

Comment: What's wrong with if blocks? Use variables. Use if. They're useful. Nothing is wrong with them.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you’re thinking of doing something along the lines of this:

```
someMethod(...collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

But only invoke the `someMethod` if the passed in list is not empty while avoiding `if` statements and temporary variables.

Matter of fact is It’s not possible to prevent the method invocation at the point of passing data in.

Your options are limited and they’re as follows:

1. Store the list into a temporary variable before the call to `someMethod`, check if `!tempList.isEmpty()` and if that’s true then invoke the method with the list else do nothing.
2. Do the handling as the first thing in the `someMethod` and exit the method immediately if the list is empty using `return;` if it’s a `void` returning method else throw an exception or return some value to indicate the list cannot be processed.

Comment: If the questioner is _really_ set on avoiding `if` blocks there may be another convoluted option: Wrap `...collect(toList())` in an `Optional.of` and then call `filter(list -> !list.isEmpty()).ifPresent(list -> someMethod(list))`... though I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: @Slaw Good shout!. That’s actually a clever idea but may just be too clever for its own good. Ultimately if the OP is just having some fun with it then I guess there is no harm in using that approach but should be avoided for producing code as it loses readability as you’ve hinted.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've got the following two methods:

```
private boolean canConsumeList(List<?> list) {
    return !list.isEmpty();
}

private <T> void consumeNonEmptyList(List<T> nonEmptyList) {
    // logic here
}
```

you could "hack" the `Collector` API like this:

```
public final class ExtraCollectors {

    public static <T, R> Collector<T, ?, ?> collectingAndConsuming(Collector<T, ?, R> downstream, Predicate<R> resultFilter, Consumer<R> resultConsumer) {
        return Collectors.collectingAndThen(downstream, result -> {
            if (resultFilter.test(result)) {
                resultConsumer.accept(result);
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```

and then use it as follows:

```
Stream.of("a", "b").collect(ExtraCollectors.collectingAndConsuming(
        Collectors.toList(), this::canConsumeList, this::consumeNonEmptyList
));
```

Note, however, that such a solution isn't something I'd consider "clean code" (that's why I called it a "hack"). It may be unintuitive for other developers because `collect` collocates with obtaining some result (or, in other words, "collecting" the elements of the `Stream` into a single result). And here, there's no result (even my IDE complains that the "result of `Stream.collect()` is ignored").